# Charge Subscription After Account Verification

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I am developing an online subscription based application where I would like to collect the user's payment information (PayPal or credit card) during the sign up process but not charge them until they have confirmed their email address.  Once I collect their name, password and payment information, an account will be created in my application.  Once created, a verification email will be sent asking them to confirm their account.  Once they click the link in the email, I will mark their account as confirmed and then ask PayPal to fulfill the subscription.  I was wondering how do I go about doing this or what is the best option for this flow?  I read about PayPal's 'Saved Payments' feature but not sure if that is the best option.  Is there a way to create a subscription as 'Pending' then once the user verifies their email address, change the subscription to some other state to process the payment?   Or... Is there way to create a subscription in a deactivated state then activate it once the user verifies their email address?

Thanks for any responses.

I have only read the documentation.  Have implemented the 'Create Subscription' based on PayPal's documentation but have not test it because, based on the documentation, will not produce the outcome that I want.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a subscription, you can specify that it should not start in an active state after approval, and be activated via API later. See the [Subscriptions API documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_create), `application_context.user_action`

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to implement your suggestion for payment sources specific to PayPal but your suggestion did not work for subscriptions created with a credit card payment source.  Is there a way to implement the same process for credit cards?